# Parsing parent and child element into a csv using jq

Tags: json, shell, csv, select, jq

I have a big file that has lines as below.

```
{
 "total": 320,
 "assets": [
   {
     "audit": {
       "created": {
         "date": "2019-09-30T12:38:01.421Z"
       },
       "updated": {}
     },
     "organizationId": "12345678",
     "id": 211123898,
     "name": "groupId:760c47ad-c9f2958be:assetId:8o-api",
     "exchangeAssetName": "8O API",
     "groupId": "760c47ad-c9f2958be",
     "assetId": "8o-api",
     "apis": [
       {
         "audit": {
           "created": {
             "date": "2019-09-30T12:38:03.139Z"
           },
           "updated": {
             "date": "2020-03-09T21:37:55.745Z"
           }
         },
      "organizationId": "12345678",
         "id": 15822364,
         "groupId": "760c47ad-c9f2958be",
         "assetId": "8o-api",
         "assetVersion": "1.0.0",
         "productVersion": "v1",
         "description": null,
         "tags": [],
         "order": 1,
         "providerId": null,
         "deprecated": false,
         "lastActiveDate": "2021-01-15T22:43:33.881Z",
         "isPublic": false,
         "stage": "release",
         "lastActiveDelta": 7,
         "pinned": false,
         "activeContractsCount": 6,
         "autodiscoveryInstanceName": "v1:15822364"
       }
     ],
     "totalApis": 1,
     "autodiscoveryApiName": "groupId:760c47ad-c9f2958be:assetId:8o-api"
   },
 {
     "audit": {
       "created": {
         "date": "2018-06-22T19:41:35.760Z"
       },
       "updated": {
         "date": "2018-09-13T06:20:51.151Z"
       }
     },
     "organizationId": "760c47ad-c9f2958be",
     "id": 210914379,
     "name": "hips-ts",
     "exchangeAssetName": "hips-ts",
     "groupId": "760c47ad-c9f2958be",
     "assetId": "hips-ts",
     "apis": [
       {
         "audit": {
           "created": {
             "date": "2018-06-22T19:41:35.759Z"
           },
           "updated": {
             "date": "2020-03-09T21:37:55.745Z"
           }
         },
         "organizationId": "760c47ad-c9f2958be",
         "id": 15470738,
         "groupId": "760c47ad-c9f2958be",
         "assetId": "hips-ts",
         "assetVersion": "1.0.0",
         "productVersion": "v1",
         "description": null,
         "tags": [],
         "order": 1,
         "providerId": null,
         "deprecated": false,
         "lastActiveDate": "2021-01-15T22:43:30.004Z",
         "endpointUri": null,
         "isPublic": false,
         "stage": "release",
         "lastActiveDelta": 11,
         "pinned": false,
         "activeContractsCount": 1,
         "autodiscoveryInstanceName": "1-test"
       }
     ],
     "totalApis": 1,
     "autodiscoveryApiName": "hips-ts"
   }
 ]
}
```

I am trying to use jq to just get the `assetId` and the `activeContractsCount` from this in a comma separated way.
So my output for this text should be

```
8o-api, 6
hips-ts, 1
```

I tried the following wiht jq `jq -r '[.assets[].assetId, .assets[].apis[].activeContractsCount]|@csv'` and I tried mapping too but nothing seems to stick.
Can you help me here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/45982943

Answer (score 1):

The following will produce exactly two columns, one for the "assetID" and one for the count:

```
.assets[].apis[]
| [.assetId, .activeContractsCount]
| @csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out as soon as I posted the question. But please let me know if there's a better way to do this.
`jq -r '.assets[]|[.apis[].assetId, .apis[].activeContractsCount]|@csv'`